# Django web page shows error when running server

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, webserver

I have just started a Django project and spun up a web server. I have made minimal changes which I will post below. When I start my server, I am given a url which I click on to navigate to my web app. I see the following error [image: Error message]

I am running `python manage.py runserver` to run my server

Following are the only changes I have made to the files:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePageView

urlpatterns = [
path('', HomePageView, name='home'),
]
```

urls.py in the project folder

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls'))
]
```

views.py

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse

def HomePageView(request):
    return HTTPResponse("Hello Django")
```

Comment: Why are you returning a `http.client.HTTPResponse` and not `django.http.HttpResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong import, this is how it should be written to avoid the error,

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def HomePageView(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Django")
```

Notice I removed your first import line and changed the return statement.